# Ajax: live display of JSON file values too slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, live

I have a button on my site, that when pressed sets the corresponding value in an JSON file to either 0 or 1. A function is continuously running and updating the color of the button depending of the JSON file. This is needed so the button has the same state on all devices.

Now my Problem: It is slow. I want it to be instantly on at least the device the button is clicked. I tried it by setting the color at the same time as the JSON file is updated, but this is buggy since the Ajax call takes some time and the button sometimes flickers. I made the following test: Every time the getStatus() function was called it would add either 1 or 0 to a div. I noticed that after the JSON changed it would still print out the old state a few times before printing the correct one, eventhought i turned cache off
Is there a way to make it faster? Here is the code:

Inex.html:

```
function getStatus() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'status.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: 'false',
        success: function(data) {
            varstatus = data;
            setColor();
            getStatus();
        }
    })
}
```

Index.php

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('status.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString);
$data[$_GET['id']] = "$f";
$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('status.json', $newJsonString);
```

Another problem I have is that the page is not alway working at the first time. I have to reload to make the updates show, but then it works without.

Or is there another way to do this, without continuously downloading the file?

Comment: First off, it sounds like your JavaScript is not waiting for the document to be ready before running.  I can't help you with that, because you didn't post that part of your code.  Second, it sounds like you would be better off with some push notification from the server.  Socket.IO is a good solution for providing web socket and web-socket-like functionality that works with most browsers.  I suggest using it with Node.js, as it is a lot easier to get working than with PHP at the moment.

Comment: using getJSON would likely get rid of the non-updating problem because each GET is s different URL. calling it over and over as fast as possible generate a lot of work on the server, slowing it down. you might want to slow down your infinite loop with a setTimeout(getStatus, 999 ) instead of just getStatus() to speed things up. checking just once a second or two will probably actually decrease the delay of updates because of the vastly less traffic your server would have to handle.

Comment: I can show you the file, but it is too large, what is a good site too paste the code?